# How can I specify multiple txids in createrawtransaction function?

Tags: transactions

I saw we can specify multiple txids, but I've never seen such a case.
So I wanna make it sure.
Thanks

Comment: Can you explain a bit more in detail? Or provide the. Example that you have seen? Do you want to use several inputs to be sent to a single output address?

Comment: Yeah exactly I want to use several inputs for an output.

Comment: Adam provided the answer already :-)

Comment: I see I thought that it was the way of multi payment

Answer (score 1):

Send the command as following:

```
bitcoin-cli createrawtransaction 
[{"txid":"FIRST_INPUT_TXID","vout":2},    
{"txid":"SECOND_INPUT_TXID", "vout":3}]
{"FIRST_OUTPUT_ADDRESS":0.006, "SECOND_OUTPUT_ADDRESS":0.004}
```

if it didn't work try to skip quotation (") by adding backslash before it \"